# C# Nested Dictionary from Excel

Tags: c#

Say you have a excel sheet with Country, State and Name. I want to create a dictionary to group all names under its respectives states and all states to its countries.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
//IMPORTANT SECTION
var dictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>>();

//iterate over the rows and columns as it appears in the file
//excel is not zero based!!
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    //it would be nice if we add some null checking to these variables
    //so, check the article
    var country = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
    var state = xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString();
    var name = xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString();

    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(country))
    {
        //var newList = new HashSet<string>();
        dictionary[country] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>();
    }

    if (!dictionary[country].ContainsKey(state))
    {
        dictionary[country][state] = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to add Name after this.

Do I have to replace the string for a list?

Comment: Instead of doing a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries, you could try creating a class that holds all of those values and do one dictionary of <string, yourClass>. This way all the data is kept in one object and you dont have a dictionary mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an extra dictionary in there. I think it should be: `Dictionary<countryName, Dictionary<stateName, HashSet<name>>()`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>();

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    var country = xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString();
    var state = xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString();
    var name = xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString();

    // Add this country if it doesn't exist
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(country))
    {
        dictionary.Add(country, new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>());
    }

    // Add this state if it doesn't exist
    if (!dictionary[country].ContainsKey(state))
    {
        dictionary[country].Add(state, new HashSet<string>());
    }

    // Add this name if it doesn't exist
    if (!dictionary[country][state].Contains(name))
    {
        dictionary[country][state].Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I actually have more so I made a mistake when simplifying. When I do it that way, I get an error at the second name that is added to same country and state. How can I deal with that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"When I do it that way, I get an error at the second name that is added to the same country and state"* The code above checks first if a country, state, or name exists before trying to add it. Can you re-phrase the issue?

Comment: Note: updated code to use `.Add()` method instead of index assignment

Comment: Forget about my comment, It was a mistake on my end.